# How Can I Assign The Result of A Beautiful Soup Request To An Array?

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

I want to have an array `urls[]` so I can check and remove duplicates. My current code looks like

```
match2 = soup.find_all("a", href=True, target="_blank");
for match2 in match2:
    if match2['href'][0] == ".":
        imageUrl = url.split("/")[2] + "/" + url.split("/")[3] + "/src/" + match2['href'].split("/")[-1];
        urls = [];
        urls.append(imageUrl);
print("array");
for i in urls:
   print(i);
```

But when I run the code there is only one element in `urls[]` when there should be more. How can I assign the results of `match2` to an array?

Comment: Can you share at which point in your code you believe you should have a list with more than one member? You’re overwriting `urls` with a blank list in every iteration of your loop, why are you doing so if you want to enumerate all your matches into said list?

Answer (score 1):

Consider initializing your URL list outside of the for loop so it isn't overridden.

Your for loop header may also have unintended consequences when using the same variable for both the iterable variable and list `for match2 in match2`.

```
match2 = soup.find_all("a", href=True, target="_blank");
urls = []
for entry in match2:
    if entry['href'][0] == ".":
        imageUrl = url.split("/")[2] + "/" + url.split("/")[3] + "/src/" + 
        entry['href'].split("/")[-1];
        urls.append(imageUrl);
 print("array");
 for i in urls:
     print(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding urls in each time you enter the if. you need to declare it outside the loop:

```
urls = [];
match2 = soup.find_all("a", href=True, target="_blank")
for match in match2:
    if match ['href'][0] == ".":
        imageUrl = url.split("/")[2] + "/" + url.split("/")[3] + "/src/" + match['href'].split("/")[-1]
        urls.append(imageUrl)
print("array")
for i in urls:
   print(i)
```